# bash: $[<arithmetic-expression>] vs. $((<arithmetic-expression>))

Tags: bash, syntax, operators, legacy, arithmetic-expressions

I have just stumbled upon the bash syntax:

```
foo=42
bar=$[foo+1] # evaluates an arithmetic expression
```

When I Googled for this, I found  http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_05:

> 3.4.6. Arithmetic expansion
>
> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and the substitution of the result. The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
> $(( EXPRESSION ))
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Wherever possible, Bash users should try to use the syntax with square brackets:
>
> ```
> $[ EXPRESSION ]
> ```
>
> However, this will only calculate the result of EXPRESSION, and do no tests...

In my bash man page I can only find the `$(( EXPRESSION ))` form such as:

```
foo=42
bar=$((foo+1)) # evaluates an arithmetic expression
```

So what tests are not performed with `$[...]` that do with `$((...))`, or is the `$[...]` just a legacy version of `$((...))`?

Comment: For a historical perspective, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40048865/2908724.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The manpage for bash v3.2.48 says:

> [...] The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
>      $((expression))
> ```
>
> The **old format $[expression] is deprecated** and will be removed in upcoming versions
>   of bash.

So `$[...]` is old syntax that should not be used anymore.

Comment: Note that exact text is not in [*the* bash man page](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html), it's in *some* bash man pages (e.g. [Debian patch this](http://patch-tracker.debian.org/patch/series/view/bash/4.1-3/man-arithmetic.dpatch)). The feature has been deprecated since bash-2.0, but persists today (bash-4.2).

Answer (score 13):

@sth is entirely correct. And in case you are curious about why a more verbose syntax is now in favor, check out this old email from the mailing list.

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00033.html

> In early proposals, a form $[expression] was used. It was functionally
> equivalent to the "$(())" of the current text, but objections were
> lodged that the 1988 KornShell had already implemented "$(())" and
> there was no compelling reason to invent yet another syntax.
> Furthermore, the "$[]" syntax had a minor incompatibility involving
> the patterns in case statements.

I am not sure that I like the rationale “but someone has already done this more verbosely,” but there you have it—maybe the case-statement problem was more compelling than I am imagining from this obscure mention?

Comment: More importantly, `$(( ))` was standardized by POSIX.2 (published in the early 1990s), and `$[ ]` was not.