# Is $(( expr )) equivalent to $[ expr ] in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic-expressions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash: $[<arithmetic-expression>] vs. $((<arithmetic-expression>))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression)

The `$(( expr ))` construct can be used for integer [math](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) in bash, e.g.

```
echo $(( 2*2 + 1 )) # 5
```

`$[ expr ]` seems to do to do the same (but isn't documented):

```
echo $[ 2*2 + 1 ] # 5
```

Are these constructs equivalent in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man bash` says:

> The format for  arithmetic  expansion is:
>
> ```
>         $((expression))
> ```
>
> The  old  format  $[expression]  is  deprecated  and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.

Comment: Just FYI, the man page doesn't say this anyone according to a search for `$[` and other phrases in this.