# environment scope in loop (for vs. while)

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I want to source files in a directory, I tried to make it work with this loop :

```
ls -1 $HOME/.bash_complete.d |while read f; do
    . $HOME/.bash_complete.d/$f
done
```

though the scripts seem to be executed, any `export foo=bar` in those are not present in env

Its `for` counterpart below :

```
for f in $HOME/.bash_complete.d/*; do
    . $f
done
```

works as I expect. Is there a scope involved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 and the answer to [Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma) (which this question is a duplicate of), everything in the while loop is executed in a subshell, so it has it's own scope. variables declared in this scope will not be visible from outside the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The `-l` is not required, which gives a long listing of the files. All that is required is the name of the files, which can be obtained by a simple `ls` command

```
ls $HOME/.bash_complete.d |while read f; do
    echo $HOME/.bash_complete.d/$f
    $HOME/.bash_complete.d/$f
done
```

Comment: it's a -1 (one), and executing the files without `source` does nothing

Comment: isnt it `. $f` instead of `. $HOME/.bash_complete.d/$f`