# Busybox ash bug - cannot concat strings in while loop?

Tags: busybox, ash

When programming with Busybox ash, `str` in following program will be changed in every `while` loop as expected, but after while loop the `str` becomes empty again. `/tmp/term_mon_ttys` is a test file.

```
#!/bin/ash
cnt=0
str=
cat /tmp/term_mon_ttys | while read line; do
    str="$str $cnt"
    cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
echo $str
```

However, if changing above code to

```
#!/bin/ash
cnt=0
str=
while [ $cnt -lt 5 ]; do
    str="$str $cnt"
    cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
echo $str
```

then after the `while` loop, the str becomes `0 1 2 3 4`.

Anybody noticed this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an ash issue.  The pipe creates a subshell so $str inside the while loop is not the same as the one outside.

This turns up regularly in shells.  You can read more here: [Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma)