# Bash problems with string comparison

Tags: bash

I have a problem with writing bash script. The problem is in comparison of strings. When I launch it, there's no errors. However  in result, it is always changing the variable **client**.
So if for an example we have two lines in file

```
apple A
orange D
```

and if I give the `who=A` I expect to see in result apple, or if at D - orange

But no matter of what I choose A or D it is always giving me the result - orange

No matter of the strings, it always change the variable **client**, like ignoring the comparison. Please help.

```
while read line
do
    IFS=" "
    set -- $line
    echo $2" "$who":"$1
    if [[ "$2"="$who" ]]
    then
        echo "change"
        client=$1
    fi
done < $file

echo $client
```

So now I changed the code as in one of the comment below, but now the caparison always false therefore the variable client is always empty

```
    while read -r line
do
    #IFS=" "
    #set -- $line
    #echo $2" "$who":"$1
    #if [[ "$2" = "$who" ]]
    a="${line% *}"
    l="${line#* }"
    if [[ "$l" == "$who" ]]
    then
        echo "hi"
        client="$a"
    fi
done < $file
```

Comment: using unquoted variables inside `[ ]` isn't a good idea...you can use unquoted variables inside `[[ ]]` though.. It deals with white spaces nicely

Comment: [[ "$2"="$who" ]] is an assignment which is always true...

Comment: so that is my question - why is it always true?

Comment: because the assignment isn't failing...

Comment: I know that it is not failing, my question how to make it failed and work properly

Comment: the problem solved? thanks every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data in a file with each line like `apple D` and you want to read the file and separate then items, the **parameter expansion/substring extraction** is the correct way to process the line. For example (**note** `$who` is taken from your problem statement):

```
while read -r line
do
    fruit="${line% *}"       # remove from end to space
    letter="${line#* }"      # remove from start to space
    if [[ "$letter" == "$who" ]]
    then
        echo "change"
        client="$fruit"
    fi
done < $file
```

---

**Short Example**

Here is a quick example of splitting the words with **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    fruit="${line% *}"
    letter="${line#* }"
    echo "fruit: $fruit  letter: $letter"
done

exit 0
```

**input**

```
$ cat dat/apple.txt
Apple A
Orange D
```

**output**

```
$ bash apple.sh <dat/apple.txt
fruit: Apple  letter: A
fruit: Orange  letter: D
```

Comment: yes it is work, as same as my method, but the problem in comparison not in reading strings...

Answer (score 1):

Change `if [[ "$2"="$who" ]]` to

```
if [[ "$2" = "$who" ]]
```

spaces around `=`

Example (for clarification):

```
who=A
while read line
do

    IFS=" "
    set -- $line
    echo $2" "$who":"$1
    if [[ "$2" = "$who" ]]
    then
        echo "change"
        client=$1
    fi
done < file #this is the file I used for testing

echo $client
```

Output:

```
A A:apple
change
D A:orange
apple
```

For `who=D`:

```
A D:apple
D D:orange
change
orange
```

Comment: This should work, are you sure there's no other problem in your code. It gives correct result in my case..

Comment: I changed my code and it is still doesn't work, just look my edit code in the original post

Comment: your new code works on me, output is apple for A and Orange for D. You sure you haven't forgotten to put `who=A` or `who=D` in the code? I don't see that assignment in your code...

Comment: Yes I find a mistake it is was in argument, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You do need spaces around that `=` operator.

However, I think you're facing yet another issue as you're trying to change the value of the `client` variable from inside the `while` loop (which executes in a subshell). I don't think that will work; see [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma) for details.