# how can I change SLEEP time in a running bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sleep

Appendix: the code below runs fine, as Matthias pointed out. The err happened at another place. In short: if you want that `sleep` is changed during script runtime, e.g. due to a certain event, you might use the code below.

Original description:

My bash script ought to check a certain status - e.g. the existence of a file - every 5 minutes. If the status is as expected, everything is fine. But if the status is otherwise, the checks ought to happen in a shorter frequency, until everything is normal again.

Example:

```
NORMAL_SLEEP=300
SHORT_SLEEP=30
CUR_SLEEP=''

while :
do

if [ -f /tmp/myfile ]; then
    logger "myfile still exists. Next check in 5min"
    CUR_SLEEP=$NORMAL_SLEEP
else
     logger "myfile disappeared. Check again in 30s!"
     CUR_SLEEP=$SHORT_SLEEP
     echo "/tmp/myfile was removed. Check this!" \
     | mailx -s "alert: myfile missed" johndoe@somewhere.com
fi

trap 'kill $SLEEP_PID; exit 1' 15
sleep $CUR_SLEEP &
SLEEP_PID=$!
wait

done
```

Problem: the sleep time does not adapt...

Had a look at [Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma) but unfortunately can't see how it could solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma)

Comment: Which sleep length is it stuck on, if it does not adapt? Also, do the messages change - which ones come out?

Comment: @MarkSetchell sleep stays at default 300s/5min; messages are correct because the missing file is recognised, but the intended change of sleep does not happen. Checks keep running every 5mins.

Comment: @Aaron `CUR_SLEEP` isn't set in any subshells here.

Comment: @chepner agreed, but the post presented the code as an example, so I thought it might be worth a shot. I should just have linked the question rather than tagged as duplicate though.

Comment: @Aaron is it possible to remove the duplicate tag? Thanks for your support, anyway!

Comment: @MarkHelms sure, removed ; technically the question should be closed as the error couldn't be reproduced with the posted code though, the reasoning being that it won't help people checking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code ran fine on my machine. Here's what I ran (changed the time values just to test):

- `./script.sh` --> "myfile disappeared. Check again in 30s!" printed at 2 sec intervals
- `touch /tmp/myfile`
- `./script.sh` --> "myfile still exists. Next check in 5min" printed at 5 sec intervals

The file, `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

NORMAL_SLEEP=5
SHORT_SLEEP=2
CUR_SLEEP=''

while :
do

if [ -f /tmp/myfile ]; then
    echo "myfile still exists. Next check in 5min"
    CUR_SLEEP=$NORMAL_SLEEP
else
     echo "myfile disappeared. Check again in 30s!"
     CUR_SLEEP=$SHORT_SLEEP
     echo "/tmp/myfile was removed. Check this!" \
     | mailx -s "alert: myfile missed" johndoe@somewhere.com
fi

trap 'kill $SLEEP_PID; exit 1' 15
sleep $CUR_SLEEP &
SLEEP_PID=$!
wait

done
```

And I probably sent some mail to `johndoe@somewhere.com` but that's okay.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I had a glitch further down my script, where I evaluated a variable falsely and thus reset the sleep to default (not to see in the example above). Sorry.