# How to avoid subshell behaviour using while and find?

Tags: bash, while-loop, find, subshell

Because I trapped into this myself, I asked a question and did give also the answer here. If `find` iterates over what the command did find, this is executed from `bash` in a subshell. So you can not fill an array with results and use it after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the syntax from:

```
i=0
find $cont_dirs_abs -type l -exec test -e {} \; -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' lxc_storage_abspath; do
    lxcname=${lxc_storage_abspath##*/}
    ...
    lxcnames[$i]="$lxcname"
    let "i+=1"
done
```

to

```
i=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' lxc_storage_abspath; do
    lxcname=${lxc_storage_abspath##*/}
    ...
    lxcnames[$i]="$lxcname"
    let "i+=1"
done < <(find $cont_dirs_abs -type l -exec test -e {} \; -print0)
```

In my case i can after this loop access the bash array `$lxcnames`:

```
i=0
for lxcname in ${lxcnames[*]}; do
    ...
done
```

Hope that helps anybody.

Comment: Find the original question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/while-loop-subshell-dilemma-in-bash