# Bash Script Issue about counts number of digits

Tags: bash

I started to take lesson to learn bash script. I want to write a bash script that asks a user to enter an integer and counts the number of digits.

How  can I use `x=$(($x+1))` to increment my counter?

Comment: You can omit **second** `$` but the syntax is correct. See: `x=3; x=$(($x+1)); echo "$x"`

Comment: Could you share your code with me cause I am really confused.

Comment: Take a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13727116/3121039) and the Bash FAQ (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) and this analysis (https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash).

Answer (score 0):

simple_code.sh

```
echo "Enter a number"
read num
echo "Number of digits in your number = ${#num}"
```

run

```
bash simple_code.sh
```