while read - change global variable on bash linux
This simple code really confused me
n=0
cat file.txt | while read line ;
do
n=1
done
echo $n

output  >> 0
Why ???!!!!!
Why does the public variable not change? I expect the value 1 to be printed ,
comment :
The file has 100 lines

certainly a dup.  The commands in a pipeline run in a subshell.

https://superuser.com/questions/1786537/why-the-variable-doesnt-change-even-if-it-should

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/while-loop-subshell-dilemma-in-bash

See also BashPitfalls and BashFAQ/024.

Shellcheck identifies several problems with the code (including the reasons why the value of n is not changed by the loop).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.
