# nested for loop cross pollution

Tags: bash, for-loop

I want to combine a large group of CSVs into multiple 1 million line files and somehow the file names of the CSVs are polluting my output in large groups.  There is no place where I'm echoing the $file variable so I'm confused as to why they end up in my output.

The data I'm using is checked into [github](https://github.com/umbrae/reddit-top-2.5-million/tree/master/data)

```
batchnum=1
ctr=1
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `ls -1 *.csv`
do
  for data in `cat $file`
  do
    echo $data >> batch${batchnum}.csv
    ctr=$[ctr + 1]
    if [ $ctr -eq 1000000 ]
    then
      batchnum=$[$batchnum + 1]
      ctr=1
  fi
  done
done
```

It's not really a critical issue but it has left me scratching my head.

Comment: There are several [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) in the above script. One of them might be at fault, although I can't trivially pinpoint any of them as the direct cause of your complaint. But it seems to me the entire script can be rewritten in one line: `cat *.csv | split -l 1000000 -`

Comment: Thanks for that, this is a far more elegant solution.

Comment: The `$[ctr + 1]` notation is curious.  It looks like it is an [undocumented](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) variant on `$((ctr + 1))`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I first discovered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515964/counter-increment-in-bash-loop-not-working) .  There is discussion on that post about that form being deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of those CSV files have data in them that look like globs to the shell. Since your script does `echo $data` in an unquoted manner, you will see the contents of the entire directory expanded as globs in your output. You could fix this by using more quotes:

```
echo "$data" >> batch${batchnum}.csv
```

Which would also cause bash not to clobber whitespace. Or you could disable glob expansion:

```
set -f
echo $data >> batch${batchnum}.csv
```