# how to increase part of a variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Hi guys I have the following function in linux script.

```
#!/bin/bash
function add1{
   echo $1
   var1=$1
   echo input + 1 is [$var1+1]
}
add 1
```

I want to take the input and add 1. So if the input was input_1 i want to return input_2.
My code is currently printing input_1+1. I think this is because I am trying to add a integer to a string but i'm not sure of any other way I could do this. 
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: input_1  is of type string, how can you expect it to do normal integer type operations!

Comment: this is what i was thinking. So in this case it makes it impossible to do?

Comment: Try to change the [$var1+1] part with the built-in bash calculator expressions: `$(($var1 + 1))` or even `$(($1+1))` (you don't need `var1`). Also, the function name is `add1`, not `add`.

Comment: @John - NO, it is not impossible. If the nature of the input will always be same, you can split the string at `_`, and add the numbers and again append with the splitted first-half. But, you've to do all of this using script. *(NOTE - I'm not a bash expert.)*

Comment: thank you @Am_I_Helpful I will try to split the string then.

Comment: See: [Counter increment in Bash loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10515964/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a syntax error with your code because you missed a space, and then your function is named `add1` but you call `add`.  The function declaration should be:

```
function add {
```

However that is not POSIX compliant, `add() {` is preferred.

There are several ways to achieve what you are asking.  Here is mine:

```
#!/bin/bash

add() {
   var1=$1
   num=${var1##*_}       # Extract the number after the _
   name=${var1%%_*}      # Extract the name before the _

   echo "input + 1 is: ${name}_$((num+1))"
}
add input_1
```

Gives:

```
input + 1 is: input_2
```

Note the arithmetic operation where I add 1 to `num` is `$((num+1))`

Comment: If the input should support multiple `_`, e.g. `foo_bar_1`, then the name should be extracted with `name=${var1%_*}` (only single `%` in order to cut  away the *shortest* match). This extracts `foo_bar`, whereas the solution with two `%%` would extract just `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-line solution:

```
function add() {
  echo "input + 1 is: ${1%_*}_$((${1##*_}+1))"
}
```