# Difference between bracket and double parentheses?

Tags: bash, command-line

What's the difference between these two? Example:

```
$ echo $((1+1))
2
$ echo $[1+1]
2
```

[As shown here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html) at [Chapter 10, Section 2](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2).

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces

Comment: thanks, wrong results came up with google.

Answer (score 1):

`$[expression]` is deprecated syntax, to accomplish same thing.

Comment: why did they deprecate it?

Comment: ask them :P (I don't know why they did :( ... )

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11911564/1983854 over there they quote the reasons (interesting, by the way).