# Fill a bash array from a NUL separated input

Tags: arrays, bash, stdin, nul

I want to create a bash array from a NUL separated input (from stdin).

Here's an example:

```
## Let define this for clarity
$ hd() { hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "'; echo ;}
$ echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0" | hd
41 20 42 00 43 0A 44 00 45 00
```

So this is my input.

Now, working with NUL works fine if not using the `-a` of `read` command:

```
$ while read -r -d '' v; do echo -n "$v" | hd; done < <(echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0")
41 20 42 
43 0A 44 
45
```

We get the correct values. But I can't store these values using `-a`:

```
$ read -r -d '' -a arr < <(echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="A" [1]="B")'
```

Which is obviously not what I wanted. I would like to have:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="A B" [1]="C
D" [2]="E")'
```

Is there a way to go with `read -a`, and if it doesn't work, why? Do you know a simple way to do this (avoiding the `while` loop) ?

Comment: Why avoid the while loop? The while loop is the FAQ-approved, irc.freenode.org/#bash-blessed Right Way to do this.

Comment: ...mind you, I'd very much prefer that `readarray` or `mapfile` supported NUL delimiters, but as of Bash 4.3, they don't. Perhaps someone should ask Chet if a patch would be accepted...

Comment: I'm using a ``while`` loop. I was just wondering why this didn't work, and wan't to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. Any details (bug report, source code link, OS limitations, sourced acknowledgement of this lack) that would give more information about the 'why' ?

Comment: `-d` provides the delimiter used by `read -a` to tell it **when to stop reading entirely, not when to stop reading a single entry**. Does that make behavior more clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`read -a` is the wrong tool for the job, as you've noticed; it only supports non-NUL delimiters. The appropriate technique is given in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
arr=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' entry; do
  arr+=( "$entry" )
done
```

---

In terms of *why* `read -d '' -a` is the wrong tool: `-d` gives `read` an argument to use to determine when to stop reading entirely, rather than when to stop reading a single element.

Consider:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -d $'\n' words; do
  ...
done
```

...this will read words separated by tab characters, until it reaches a newline. Thus, even with `read -a`, using `-d ''` will read *until it reaches a NUL*.

What you want, to read until no more content is available and split by NULs, is not a '-d' of NUL, but no end-of-line character at all (and an empty `IFS`). This is not something `read`'s usage currently makes available.

Comment: You probably wanted to point to [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005). As the #1 doesn't speak about arrays.

Comment: @vaab, #1 speaks *directly* to reading NUL-delimited input. Look for the example describing correct use with `find -print0`.

Comment: There's only one mention of the word 'array' in #1, and it tells to go to #5. I feel #5 answers my concerns, not #1. I definitively know how to read NUL separated content with ``read`` as shown in the question itself.

Comment: @vaab, it doesn't say "array", but it does speak to NUL-delimited text. Search for `-print0`.

Answer (score 3):

bash-4.4-alpha added a `-d` option to `mapfile`:

> The `mapfile' builtin now has a -d option to use an arbitrary
>   character
>       as the record delimiter, and a -t option  to strip the delimiter as
>       supplied with -d.
>
> — https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES

Using this, we can simply write:

```
mapfile -t -d '' arr < <(echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0")
```

Comment: Useful addendum. That said, I'd suggest `printf '%s\0' "A B" C D E` in place of the `echo`, btw -- even on bash, `echo -e` isn't always available (for example, it just prints `-e` on output whenever both `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are active -- and the former can be made default at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders, here's the function (using `while`) that I use to store values from a `NUL`-separated `stdin`:

```
read_array () {
    local i
    var="$1"
    i=0
    while read -r -d '' value; do
        printf -v "$var[$i]" "%s" "$value"
        i=$[$i + 1]
    done
}
```

It can then be used quite cleanly:

```
$ read_array arr < <(echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0")
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="A B" [1]="C
D" [2]="E")'
```

Comment: The [bracket form of arithmetic expansion is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2415777/1157557). You could remove that line completely and increment `i` on the previous line: `"$var[i++]"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplification of @vaab's function. It uses [bash 4.3's nameref](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare#nameref) feature:

```
read_array () {
  local -n a=$1
  while read -r -d '' value; do
    a+=("$value")
  done
}
```

Test:

```
test_it () {
  local -a arr
  read_array arr < <(echo -en "A B\0C\nD\0E\0")
  declare -p arr
}
test_it
```