# bash passing value as a parameter calculation

Tags: bash

I wrote small bash script

```
for (( j=10;j<20; j++ ))
    do
    ./b5 $j $[ $1 * 3 ]
    done
```

Which should execute program b5 and send  two parameters, $j and $1 multiplied by 3.

When I try to run it, i get:

```
 * 3 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 3 ")
```

How should one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$((..))` for doing arithmetic expression.

Instead,

```
./b5 $j $[ $1 * 3 ]
```

to

```
./b5 $j $(($1 * 3))
```

Comment: You don't *have* to; `$[ ... ]` is an obsolete but still valid form of arithmetic expansion. The bigger problem is that `$1` doesn't appear to be set.

Comment: @chepner, Ohh..ok. I got it..thanks. I just found the difference in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression

Comment: I do wonder when it will be removed from `bash`, though; it still works in the upcoming 4.4 release.

Answer (score 1):

You should do `expr $1 \* 3` to multiply variable by a digit.

Comment: `$((...))` almost wholly subsumes the need for `expr` in any POSIX shell. The only thing you really need `expr` for is regular expression matching for shells that don't already provide their own.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, both options work:

- $(( $1 * 3 ))
- $[ $1 * 3]

but he problem was $1 was not initialized. My mistake.