# Why does bash brace expansion work in some arithmetic expressions but not others?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic-expressions, brace-expansion

I am working on a very simple bash script and I'm having a problem with understating why deprecated $[] is working flawlessly, while $(()) seems to break the whole thing.

The code I'm referring to is:

```
for i in {1..10};
do 
    printf %4d $[{1..10}*i]
    echo
done
```

In this version I am having no issues, yet I wouldn't like to use deprecated bash elements, that's why I wanted to switch to $(()).

Unfortunately, as soon as I change my code to:

```
printf %4d $(({1..10}*i))
```

I receive an error:

```
./script_bash.sh: line 8: {1..10}*i: syntax error: argument expected (error token is "{1..10}*i")
```

I'd be thankful for some help with this one...

Comment: `$(())` is an arithmetic expression. It doesn't do regular wildcard or brace expansion in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the way back machine for 1990.

Bash implemented the `$[]` syntax per POSIX P1003.2d9 (circa 1990), which was a draft of the released P1003.2-1992. In the two years between draft and standard, POSIX had instead settled on the ksh88 `$(())` syntax and behaviors. Chet Ramey (bash maintainer) had this to say, [back in 2012](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00051.html):

> Bash... implemented $[...] because there was no other
>   syntax at the time, and to gain some operational experience with
>   arithmetic expansion in the shell.  Bash-1.14... lists both forms of arithmetic expansion, but by
>   the time bash-2.0 was released in 1995, the manual referred only to
>   the $((...)) form.

This suggests to me that the `$[]` form was *experimental*, and it had certain behaviors (like brace expansion) that were specified into oblivion when POSIX adopted the `$(())` syntax. Those experimental behaviors were left in, since there were already scripts in the wild relying on them (remember more than 2 years had elapsed).

Chet makes clear in that same thread that the `$[]` form is obsolete, but not deprecated:

> Now, it's hardly any problem to keep dragging the $[...] syntax along.
>   It takes only a few dozen bytes of code.  I have no plans to remove it.

The [current POSIX standard, C.2.6 Word Expansions > Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html) mentions the syntax (emphasis mine):

> In early proposals, a form $[expression] was used. **It was functionally equivalent to the "$(())" of the current text**, but objections were lodged that the 1988 KornShell had already implemented "$(())" and there was no compelling reason to invent yet another syntax. Furthermore, the "$[]" syntax had a minor incompatibility involving the patterns in case statements.

So the as-implemented behavior in bash isn't quite to specification, but since there are no plans to remove it, I see no reason to forgo its benefits if it neatly solves your problem. However, as pointed out by @Barmar's comment, it'd be A Good Idea to comment the code and link it here so future developers know what the heck you mean!

Comment: While it's not explicitly deprecated (is there actually a list of deprecated features?), the fact that it's not even mentioned in the manual is a strong indication to avoid it. Even if it never actually goes away, other programmers will not understand it. I've been programming shell scripts for 3 decades and I never saw this before, I'm sure I'm not alone. Compare with the other features that are on the bash-hackers page you linked to, they're still in the manual.

Comment: @Barmar It's mentioned in the current POSIX specification, and [purportedly](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00033.html) some distros patch the bash man page to mention it. Nonetheless, I've elaborated on my usage "recommendation".

Answer (score 1):

`$(())` is for arithmetic expressions, and brace expansion isn't done in arithmetic.

Make an array with a loop:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    vals=()
    for j in {1..10}
    do
        vals+=($((i*j)))
    done
    printf "%4d" ${vals[@]}
done
```

Comment: But, on the flip side, why is brace expansion done in `$[]`?

Comment: This is the first I've ever heard of `$[]`. I can't find it in the bash manual.

Comment: It's a deprecated pseudo-equivalent of `$((`, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: So, I guess *technically* your first sentence isn't true, since ostensibly `$[]` is also for "arithmetic expressions."

Comment: But I guess at the time they created it, they didn't consider arithmetic expansion to be a completely different context with its own syntax.

Comment: Indeed. Did some digging and looks like `$[]` was a POSIX draft syntax before settling on the ksh `$(())` syntax. Additional details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`printf %4d $(({1..10}*i))`

does not work because of the order in which parameters are expanded in `bash`. The brace expansion (`{}`) is done earlier than arithmetic expansion (`$(())`) by `bash`. Your code would definitely work if it were other way around.

From `man bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Ran across some bash like this.  This question asks for explanation, rather than solution, but here would be a $(())-way of expressing this.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  printf %4d $(eval echo '$(('{1..10}'*i))')
  echo
done
```

Brace expansion is inhibited inside an arithmetic expansion like it is for parameter expansion.

(bash manual)

> To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion, and inhibits brace expansion
>   until the closing ‘}’.

Comment: plus one, with all the usual caveats of "eval is evil".