# why this simple while loop not working in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "enter i:" I
while [ $I -lt 4 ]
do
echo $I
I=$[$I+1]
done
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'? do you get an error/syntx message?  what output does it generate? what output are you expecting?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: "There's no output in my terminal" is what I meant by saying "It is not working."

Comment: Your learning Bash shell material is too old or has not been updated. Bash arithmetic as Bracket expression has been deprecated since 1992. \( See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40048865/7939871 \)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
read -p 'enter a positive integer < 4: >>> ' int

while ((int < 4 )); do
        echo "$int"
        ((int++))
done
```

---

```
((...))
```

is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression