# Why do the following string comparisons return different results?

Tags: bash, relational-operators

What is the difference between the following commands and why do they not produce the same output?:

```
echo $[ "a" == "a" ]

1
 
echo $(( "a" == "a" ))

1

[ "a" == "a" ]; echo $?;

0
```

Comment: `echo $[ "a" == "a" ]` results in `"bash: "a" == "a" : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""a" == "a" ")"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $[ "a" == "a" ]
```

uses the deprecated integer expansion syntax, which has been replaced by `$(( ... ))`.

```
echo $(( "a" == "a" ))
```

uses what is called arithmetic expansion: inside `$(( ... ))`, you can have logical and numerical expressions that get calculated before returning the value.

```
[ "a" == "a" ]; echo $?
```

does a logical test in standard bash fashion: the return code of a program is 0 when that program executes successfully, and non-zero otherwise. `[` is actually another name for the program called `test`, which returns success (i.e., 0) when the expression it tests is true.

Not in your list, but related:

```
(( "a" == "a" )); echo $?

0
```

this does arithmetic expansion, and returns success (0) if the result is true, rather than producing the value of the expression itself.

```
[[ "a" == "a" ]]; echo $?

0
```

`[[ ... ]]` is bash syntax for doing conditional tests directly instead of calling the program `test`.

**Some sample usages**

You would use `$(( ... ))` to initialize variables or echo output, as you did:

```
foo=$(( 1 + 4))
echo $(( 5 + 7 ))
```

You would use `[ ... ]`, `(( ... ))` and `[[ ... ]]` in conditional statements:

```
if [[ $a == bar ]]; then
   echo $a is bar
fi

i=0
while (( i < 10 )); do
   echo i=$i
   i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 3):

> To me, these seem like the same operations but the first two which are appended with $ return false...

That's incorrect. The first two expressions are *arithmetic expressions*. They produce a *numeric* result.  As is common in many languages, a boolean True evaluates as the integer value `1`, and False evaluates as `0`.

Note that `$[...]` and `$((...))` are equivalent, but the former [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression) and is no longer documented.

> ...while the third returns true

This isn't true either.  Here you are looking at the return code of a command, rather than printing out the value of an expression as you are doing in the first two examples.  Commands don't return boolean information; they return an integer indicating whether they were successful (a return code of 0) or not (any non-zero return code).

---

Regarding your question, the `false` command doesn't return "false"; if you read the man page, it says:

> false - do nothing, unsuccessfully

That is, it is a command that does nothing and returns an error code (i.e., a nonzero exit code, in this case, `1`).  `true` is similar, of course, except it returns a successful exit code (i.e., `0`).

Comment: I'm sorry if you had a problem with this answer. If you feel it didn't adequately address your question you are welcome to accept another one. Pretty sure I'm right, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two perform arithmetic comparisons (never use `$[...]`; it's undocumented, obsolete, and was replaced by `$((...))`—literally—decades ago). In an arithmetic context, strings are treated as implicit parameter expansions, recursively, until an integer is produces. Undefined parameters are treated as 0. The resulting expression has value 1 if the comparison is true, 0 if false. Compare:

```
$ echo $(( a == b ))  # Compares 0 == 0
1
$ a=5; b=7
$ echo $(( a == b ))  # Compares 5 == 7
0
```

The last one performs string comparison, as expected. The exit status of `[ ... ]` is 0 when the comparison is true, 1 when false. (This is the difference between the *value* of a Boolean expression, and the result of a *command* that evaluates a Boolean expression.) Integer comparisons are made using the `-eq` operator.

```
$ [ a = a ]; echo $?  # String comparison of the letter a to itself
0
$ [ a = b ]; echo $?  # String comparison of the letter a to the letter b
1
$ unset a b
$ [ a -eq b ]; echo $?  # Again, 0 -eq 0
0
$ a=5; b=7
$ [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]; echo $?  # Again, 5 -eq 7
1
```