# Create bash script to generate 101 svgs

Tags: html, css, bash

I am generating a progress circle with 56% as shown below as an example.

I am trying to create a bash script to generate 101 progress circle svgs ranging from 0 till 100. That is from 0% to 100% filled circles.

But it seems to not work, the progress bar for calc does not update. What is the problem here?

```css
.content{
  --val: 0;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.percent {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(100 - var(--val));
}

.val {
  --val: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle style="--val: 56" class="percent val" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
</svg>
```

```
PROGRESS="0"

while [ $PROGRESS -lt 100 ]
do
    cat <<EOS > Image/progress-circle-$PROGRESS.svg
    <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" style="$PROGRESS: 0; transform: rotate(-90deg);">
        <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="12" />
        <circle style="stroke-dasharray: 100; stroke-dashoffset: calc(100 - $PROGRESS)" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" fill="none" stroke="#f77a52" stroke-width="12" pathLength="100" />
    </svg>
EOS
    PROGRESS=$[$PROGRESS+1]
done
```

Please see this generated image:
[image: Circle]

Comment: Hi @Hamdi - `style="0: 0;`  [that's what you get putting $PROGRESS when it's 0 ... is that really what you intended??  You mentioned a progress bar for calc - what is that - there's nothing in you question showing a progress bar??  Please provide everything we need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `PROGRESS=$[$PROGRESS+1]` Where did you even find out about that ancient, decades obsolete syntax?

Comment: @MrR I have updated it. Kindly check it.

Comment: @Shawn from one of the answers I was looking for. But is that affecting it?

Comment: Anything that uses that is highly suspect as to its quality. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415724/bash-arithmetic-expression-vs-arithmetic-expression

Comment: @Hamdi - I get 100 images produced - what is the problem??  do you really want this -`<     <svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" style="98: 0; transform: rotate(-90deg);">`  notice the style is wonky??

Comment: Anyways, I'd start by running your script through https://shellcheck.net and fixing anything it points out - always a good first step for debugging shell scripts.

Comment: Not really. I just need a progress circle.

Comment: (i'd also do it with a XML-aware tool instead of just shell; maybe XSLT?)